# DB results into a ListView, data may vary

Tags: android, sql, listview, android-listview

Hi a bit new to java/android programming, I am trying to populate a listview from a database. The problem is the database output for each record may have varying results. To give you an idea I have the following layout in my xml for the listview;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#a28d7a">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/coreHeader"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:padding="4dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/coreLinear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/coreStatsLeft"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first TextView is the header of sorts, bigger font, etc.. in this area it will hold two fields from the database, the NAME and the LEVEL e.g; SPIDER-MAN (Lvl 5).

The two textfields below it will hold the stats, this area can have more than one for example;

```
Name                Value
------------------------------------
Armor                 10%
Speed                  5%
... and so on
```

Each record can be different, some may not have speed, some may not have armor... Maybe this is too difficult to do via ListView, but I need it to be searchable and I do not know what other options I have available for this.

My database fields are as follows:

### Id, Name, Level, Stats

an example of the populated db would read;

1, Spider-Man, 5, 3|10%;5|5%;6|3%

Comment: Are you populating each item of the listview from an Adapter and getting the data from local storage like sqlite? If so, you can put the data overriding the bindView method (overriding on Custom adapter from CursorAdapter) and set visibility to GONE (findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_id).setVisibility(View.GONE)) for the items you do not have data on this row.

Comment: Well I am having trouble even determining on how I am going to attempt this.  If I use an adapter it seems to me it will just take the results of the sqlite table and populate the listview, my problem is I have to do a little bit of work before it even gets to that point. i.e; set name and level, loop through the stats.

Comment: While the View.GONE is a good idea, the problem is there are 176 different possibilities. I do not think I want to add 176 TextView's in an XML file.

Comment: You can add dynamically the TextView depending of the data you have for this row. I will answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a example to show how to add variable data to each row in a listview.

This is the Activity implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private DynamicAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Simulating variable data per row. Array Adapter instead Cursor Adapter for simplicity
        final DataRow[] data =
                {
                        new DataRow("Spider Man", new String[] {"3|10%", "5|25%"}),
                        new DataRow("Spider Man Brother", new String[] {"3|20%"}),
                        new DataRow("Other Spider Man", new String[] {"3|22%", "1|12%", "4|7%"})
            };

        // Assign data to adapter
        adapter = new DynamicAdapter(this, data);

        // Getting reference to ListView
        ListView listViewData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);

        // Setting adapter to listView
        listViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is how the Adapter will put the data for each row:

```
public class DynamicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataRow>
{
    private final Context context;

    private final DataRow[] data;

    public DynamicAdapter(Context context, DataRow[] data)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, data);

        this.context = context;

        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        // Get a listview reference
        LinearLayout linearLayoutRow = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.coreLinear);

        if(position < data.length)
        {
            // Put text on header
            TextView textHeader = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.coreHeader);

            // Set the header for this row
            textHeader.setText(data[position].GetHeader());

            // Creating a vertical linear layout to put the data row
            LinearLayout linearLayoutData = new LinearLayout(context);
            linearLayoutData.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            // Get column amount for this row.
            int columnAmount = data[position].GetColumnsSize();

            for(int i = 0; i < columnAmount; i++)
            {
                // Creating dynamically a TextView for this column.                    
                TextView dynamicData = new TextView(context);

                dynamicData.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                // Adding data to TextView
                dynamicData.setText(data[position].GetDataAt(i));

                // Adding TextView to linearLayout
                linearLayoutData.addView(dynamicData);
            }

            // Adding LinearLayout to LinearLayout on XML  
            linearLayoutRow.addView(linearLayoutData);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This is the full demo on Github: https://github.com/deinier/DynamicDataOnListView

I hope this help.